# Hierarchical query to find root and return singular path

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, hierarchical

I am working with a black box database which I did not create, nor can I edit. Also, this select query needs to run in jasper reports so I cannot write a stored procedure.

I have an inventory system which uses a parent/child mapping table and produced new keys each time there is a change in inventory status. I am working with 2 tables these are the important fields and a simplified query:

allinv which contains fields:
invmaster
invkey

and

pclink which contains fields (corresponds to invkeys for allinv above):
parent 
child

The following query works for one inventory item and shows the progression as expected but it requires knowing the root and providing the master key.

My question then is, if I need to return all inventory items (remove the where clause) with this structure is there a way to automatically detect the root element and set that is the 'start with' or something that would work similarly so I can use this as a subquery to an analytical window query to pull root, leaf(s) and statuses along the way?

```
select
  ai.invkey AS sxkey,
  stl.parent as parent,
  stl.child as child,
  level as lvl,
  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF as IsLeaf,
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT(STL.parent) as root
from eprog.allinv ai
  left join eprog.pclink stl
    on ai.invkey = stl.parent
where invmasterkey = 'SA3010401'
start with stl.parent = '#gRR5'
connect by nocycle prior stl.child = stl.parent;
```

Comment: Why does it only work if you provide the root and master key? Some representative sample data and expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but you can certainly do:

```
START WITH stl.parent IS NULL
```

to start your hierarchical query with those rows.